# Chrome dev-tools doesn't show "Connection ID" for h3 requests in the network panel

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, quic, http3

As can be seen in this screenshot, the Chrome's (Version 116.0.5813.0) network panel is missing the `connection id` for any h3 request.
Is there any configuration to allow that? or it is simply not possible or doesn't make sense for QUIC connections in general?
[image]